# PHP Highlighting Different Dates

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to work out how to highlight dates dragged from a MySQL db as per the following:

- If database date is today then echo in green
- If database date is tomorrow then echo in orange
- If database date is the day after tomorrow then echo in red

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this?

I have tried the following but for some reason dates way in to the future are displayed in red. I'm not sure if the code I am using is the best way to achieve this.

```
$date=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($rows['collect_date']));

if ($date==date(("d/m/Y"), strtotime('+1 days')) && $rows['status']=='4')
{
echo "<span class='label label-danger1'>".$date."</span>";
}
elseif ($date==date(("d/m/Y")) && $rows['status']=='4')
{
echo "<span class='label label-danger'>".$date."</span>";
}
elseif ($date==date(("d/m/Y"), strtotime('+2 days')) && $rows['status']=='4')
{
echo "<span class='label label-warning'>".$date."</span>";
}
elseif (strtotime($date) < strtotime('1 day ago') && $rows['status']=='4')
{
echo "<span class='label label-danger'>".$date."</span>";
}
else 
{
echo $date;
}
```

Custom CSS:

```
.label-danger1{
  background-color: #FF6666;
}
```

Many thanks,

John

Comment: From the database, are they UNIX timestamps?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far an explain what's not working.

Comment: @PatrickQ I have edited my original post with the code I am using currently but for some reason this shows up dates well into the future as red. Thanks

Comment: It would probably help to see your CSS as well. It's possible that that's where the problem is.

Comment: @PatrickQ I have amended the post to include the only bit of custom CSS I have included. The rest is using the Twitter Bootstrap framework.

Comment: It looks like the problem is most likely the value of `$rows['collect_date']`. Can you provide us with the output of `var_dump($rows);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
if($date  == date('d/m/Y'))
echo '<span  style=" background-color: green">its today';
else
if($date  == date('d/m/Y',strtotime("+1 days")))
echo '<span  style=" background-color: orange">it will be yesterday<span>';

else
echo '<span  style=" background-color: red">it will be '.$date.'<span>';
```

Check this link also
[php mysql today, yesterday and date from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692368/php-mysql-today-yesterday-and-date-from-database/24692718#24692718)