# Php check if my date from db is today echo with today and if tomorrow then echo tomorrow

Tags: php

How to make a check if datetime from my db is today and then echo with "today" and if my datetime is tomorrow echo with tomorrow. I want to make this for a date reminder for fullcalendar.

My Php code is not working or is messed:

```
$reminder = date('d-M-Y',strtotime(date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['start'])) . " +0 days"));
$tomorrow = strtotime("+1 day");
$tomorrow = getdate($tomorrow);

if($reminder = "0 Days") {
    echo "Today";
} else if($reminder = "1 Days" ) {
    echo "Tomorrow";
} else {
    echo (strtotime($reminder) - strtotime(date('d-M-Y'))) / (60 * 60 * 24).' Days';
}
```

Comment: Give us an output of your db-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to check if a date is today, yesterday or tomorrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622370/php-how-to-check-if-a-date-is-today-yesterday-or-tomorrow)

Comment: the output is: 15-Nov-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$date='14-Nov-2017';
$time = strtotime($date);
$formatDate = date('Y-m-d',$time);
echo $formatDate;
$today=date("Y-m-d");

if($formatDate==date("Y-m-d")){
    echo "TODAY";
}
else if ($formatDate==date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' +1 days'))){
    echo 'TOMORROW';
}
else{
    echo "Another day";
}
```

This code get's the date you output , and compares it with todays date , tomorrows date otherwise just echos another date. Tested and it works also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
$diff = date_diff(date('d-M-Y'), date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['start'])));

if($diff == 0) {
    echo "Today";
} else if($diff == 1) {
    echo "Tomorrow";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your if-statements, you are setting rather than checking.

Replace your `=` with `==` in your `if`s:

```
if($reminder == "0 Days") {
    echo "Today";
} else if($reminder == "1 Days" ) {
    echo "Tomorrow";
} else {
    echo (strtotime($reminder) - strtotime(date('d-M-Y'))) / (60 * 60 * 24).' Days';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can get Date Difference using `diff` method of `DateTime` class.

I wrote common function for that. just you need to pass `Date/DateTime String format` or `instance of DateTime class`

```
<?php
    $currentDate = '2022-07-27';
    // $nextDate = '2022-07-27';
    // $nextDate = '2022-07-28';
    $nextDate = '2022-07-29';
    echo getDateToTodayTomorrowFormat($nextDate, $currentDate);


    /**
     * get Date format to number of Days difference Format ('Today', 'Tomorrow', '2 days later', '3 days later' etc.)
     *
     * @param  string|\DateTime $nextDate // eg. pass Object of DateTime class "OR" Date/Date-Time string (format :- 'Y-m-d', 'Y/m/d', 'Y-m-d H:i:s') 
     * @param  string|\DateTime $currentDate // eg. pass Object of DateTime class "OR"  Date/Date-Time string (format :- 'Y-m-d', 'Y/m/d', 'Y-m-d H:i:s') 
     * @return string
     * 
     * Date/Date-Time string must be in format of standard formats which are supported by \DateTime::class (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
     * 
     * ****
     * # Input > Output :- 
     *  $currentDate = '2022-07-27';
     * 
     *      case 1:- $nextDate = '2022-07-27',  `then OUTPUT :- "Today"` \
     *      case 2:- $nextDate = '2022-07-28',  `then OUTPUT :- "Tomorrow"` \
     *      case 3:- $nextDate = '2022-07-29',  `then OUTPUT :- "2 days later"`
     */
    function getDateToTodayTomorrowFormat($nextDate, $currentDate)
    {
        if (is_string($nextDate)) {
            $nextDate = new \DateTime($nextDate);
        }
        
        if (is_string($currentDate)) {
            $currentDate = new \DateTime($currentDate);
        }
        
        $interval = $currentDate->diff($nextDate);

       // $days = $interval->format('%r %d'); // returns like "- 1", "0", "+ 1"

        $days = $interval->days; // returns only 0 & int difference
        if($days === 0) {
            return 'Today';
        } else if($days === 1) {
            return 'Tomorrow';
        } else {
            return $days . ' days later';
        }
    }
?>
```

for more details [see this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923228/14344959)